# How to get an array of string from an xml file saved on internal storage in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-resources

I have a very simple xml file, created after the runtime, it's very similar to the res/array.xml but it's saved in the internal storage. It's something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string-array name="group0_arr">
        <item>1,name,desc</item>
        <item>2,name,desc</item>
        <item>3,name,desc</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="group1_arr">
        <item>100,name,desc</item>
        <item>101,name,desc</item>
        <item>102,name,desc</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

In my activity to get an array of string from the res/array.xml I use the code:

```
String[] arrayOfString0 context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group0_arr);
```

But to get the file on internal storage I use:

```
File darf= new File(this.getFilesDir(), "other_array.xml");
```

So how I can get the same result starting from that?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to apply the same 'simple' solution as `getResources()` for XML files other than some predefined ones like `strings.xml`. When you use `getResources()` Android already does a lot of work for you. 
If you want to use your own, custom XML file you need to parse it. 
You can do that 'by hand' with an [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) or a [DOM-Parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) or you can use a library like [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). 
It certainly won't be as convenient as the pre-defined resources that you use when using `getResources()`.

If you want to store complex data within your app, I'd strongly recommend not using XML but rather JSON in combination with [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or even an ORM library like [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/).

Comment: I also recommend going the JSON/GSON route. It is much nicer to be able to work with model objects that are parsed out by a library than it is to manually parse things out yourself.